# How to make a shared_lock or upgrade_lock in standard C++11?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex, boost-thread

I am missing very much from the new standard the `std::shared_lock` template class.
In Boost.Thread there is `boost::shared_lock`, even `boost::upgrade_lock` exists.

Why is that, there is no std::shared_lock and `std::unique_lock` in C++11? 
How is it possible to acquire a similar behavior as `boost::shared_lock` has, but in pure C++11?

I was thinking to use `boost::shared_lock<std::mutex>`, but this doesn't have so much sense, since `std::mutex` does not have a `lock_shared()` member. And also, there is no such as `std::shared_mutex`.

Comment: If you already use Boost, I think there's no point avoiding `boost::shared_mutex` in favor of `std::mutex`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Howard's proposal for `std::shared_mutex` was turned down for C++11 due to lack of time to consider it properly. He's proposed it again for C++17, and it's being discussed at the meeting in Portland this week.

In the mean time, if you can use Boost then you may as well; there won't be any new functionality for it being standardized.

That said, it's worth checking that using `shared_mutex` is actually of benefit --- in many cases it doesn't provide the hoped-for performance gains due to contention on the mutex itself.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Anthony. Since than I did some digging and find this discussion about Howard's proposal:
http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/211180